# Have Bootstrap Modal Load Faster

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal:

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal"> ... </div>
```

I have javascript code that shows the modal and then calls some form validation code:

```
$("#myModal").modal("show");
doValidation();
```

The intent of the modal is to prevent the user from doing anything while the form is being validated.  Unfortunately, the modal doesn't show up until the validation is done.  I have tried moving the validation code to an event that triggers on modal open, but even then, the modal still doesn't load fast enough.  Additionally, without the form validation code, the modal still shows up after a noticeable delay rather than instantly like I want.  How can I make the modal show up instantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the modal load instantly by setting its `display` property to `block` (it is `none` by default).

Put the following in your css:

```
.manually-show-modal {
    display:block !important;
}
```

Then, attach this class to the modal dynamically.  This can be done with angular as follows:

```
<div class="modal" ng-class="{'manually-show-modal': show_modal}" id="myModal">
```

Scope initialization:

```
$scope.show_modal = false;
```

Modal display:

```
$scope.show_modal = true;
doValidation();
```

---

A caution to this approach is that you will not be able to close the modal by normal means.  If you want the user to be able to close the modal, you will need to make a modal close button like the following:

```
<button ng-click="modalClose()">Close</button>
```

with the following in your angular controller:

```
$scope.modalClose = function() {
    $scope.show_modal = false;
}
```